# Time complexity pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to calculate the time complexity of the following code :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    func();
    .            // Other O(1) operations
    .
}
```

where func() has a complexity of O(k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity will be O(k*n) then.

Comment: Can you explain why it can't be O(n+k) ?

Comment: because you are doing the function with a speed of O(k) n times, so its O(k*n)

Comment: @Eddge time complexity and speed are not the same exact thing.

Comment: @TonyTannous indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You should realize the meaning of loop, if you use

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

The loop will be executed n times,
and every times, one loop will cost O(k)+O(1)=O(k),
so the total complexity will be O(n*k), hope this post help you!